# Grunt-open more than one page?

Tags: gruntjs

Upon startup, i'd like the page to open more than one page.

How does one, using the grunt-open plugin, open more than one page?

E.g. my configuration is this:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

  'use strict';

  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

  grunt.initConfig({
    // ... Skip through all of the other config

    open: {
        server: {
            url: 'http://localhost:<%= express.options.port %>/index.html'
        }
    },

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['server', 'open']);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up doing this like so:

```
open: {
   url1: {
      path: 'http://localhost:<%= express.options.port %>/index.html'
  },
   url2: {
      path: 'http://localhost:<%= express.options.port %>/index2.html'
    }
}
```

Source: https://github.com/jsoverson/grunt-open/issues/25#issuecomment-56428370